# sublime text 2 via gnome-Terminal GLib-CRITICAL

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, sublime-text, execute-command

Whenever I run sublime text 2 from the command line (via the 'subl' shortcut command) I receive the following error

```
(sublime_text:4679): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 15745 was not found when attempting to remove it
```

I am also not able to navigate nor preform any command in the terminal instance in which initially launched sublime.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23165426/sublime-text-on-ubuntu-14-04-keeps-attempting-to-remove-it